# SQL - How to subtract two DATE values in a column based on another column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that stores data of when a shipment arrived and when it left. I need to subtract the OUT date from the IN date based on the ARRIVAL column and display in a separate table all the shipments that have been sitting for 5 days or more. How can this be done?

Here is my table -

| ID | ARRIVAL | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | OUT | 2022-06-23 |
| C1 | IN | 2022-06-18 |
| C2 | OUT | 2022-06-20 |
| C2 | IN | 2022-06-18 |
| C3 | OUT | 2022-06-24 |
| C3 | IN | 2022-06-17 |

Expected Result -

| OVERSTAYED SHIPMENTS |
| --- |
| C1 |
| C3 |

Comment: What database are you using ?

Comment: Oracle <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: And please show desired results in addition to sample data.

Comment: I'm using Oracle database. I made changes to the question as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Test data:

```
create table my_table (id, arrival, date_col) as
  select 'C1', 'OUT', date '2022-06-23' from dual union all
  select 'C1', 'IN' , date '2022-06-18' from dual union all
  select 'C2', 'OUT', date '2022-06-20' from dual union all
  select 'C2', 'IN' , date '2022-06-18' from dual union all
  select 'C3', 'OUT', date '2022-06-24' from dual union all
  select 'C3', 'IN' , date '2022-06-17' from dual union all
  select 'C4', 'IN' , date '2022-05-30' from dual union all
  select 'C5', 'IN' , date '2022-06-20' from dual
;
```

Notice the last two rows, for id = C4, resp. C5. They only have an `'IN`' row, without an `'OUT'` row yet. In my answer, I will assume you want to find those id without an `'OUT'` row, if the `'IN'` row is currently (as of when the query is run) at least five days back.

`date` is an Oracle keyword, it should not be used as a column name. I changed the name to `date_col`; use your actual column name, which I hope is not `date`.

Query and output:

```
select id
from   my_table
pivot  (min(date_col) for arrival in ('IN' as date_in, 'OUT' as date_out))
where  date_in <= nvl(date_out, sysdate) - 5    --  example run on 2022-06-22
order  by id                                    --  or whatever you need
;

ID
--
C1
C3
C4
```

The `pivot` operation is an aggregate operation; it avoids the join used in other answers, which generally requires the same data to be read twice.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to compute add days to a date using "+". With that, it's possible to compare the dates.

```sql
SELECT i.id FROM events i JOIN events o ON i.id = o.id
WHERE i.arrival = 'IN' 
AND o.arrival = 'OUT'
AND o.date >= i.date + 5
```

In this case: i.date + 5 adds 5 days to the date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a self-join to the one table based on the common id.  However, I would SUGGEST doing a LEFT-JOIN meaning I want all from one side, regardless of an entry in the other.  So, always start with an INBOUND item, left-join to a matching OUTBOUND.  If there is no OUTBOUND version, then compute the days difference based on whatever the current date is.  ie: if it still has not shipped out today, and its been 5 days already, why wait until someone gets to the shipment 9 days later to tell the staff to expedite the work, or find out what is up.

```
select
      InRec.Id,
      datediff( coalesce( OutRec.Date, CurDate() ), InRec.Date ) DaysToShip,
      case when OutRec.Id is null then 'NOT SHIPPED' else '' end status
   from
      YourTable InRec
         LEFT JOIN YourTable OutRec
            on InRec.Id = OutRec.Id
            AND OutRec.Arrival = 'OUT'
   where
          InRec.Arrival = 'IN'
      AND datediff( coalesce( OutRec.Date, CurDate() ), InRec.Date ) >= 5
```

So, even though not specifically asked for, I included the calculation in the fields list so you can see the specific results.